# Are there standard symbols to describe discrete event simulations (DES)

Tags: modeling, reference-request, simulation

I just wonder, whether there is a good reference for the symbols used in a flow chart to describe a DES process. I am looking for something like [Kendall notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall%27s_notation) but with a reference to the symbols.
I searched the web, but could not find a good reference (e.g., a well-known journal).

Comment: Something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Process_Model_and_Notation

Answer (score 0):

Kendall notation is okay up until a point for simple queueing systems. I have found that when I have a network of queues each having substantially different properties that the notation gets awkward. Here is a post: [Kendall's Notation for Kelly Networks?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/638810/kendalls-notation-for-kelly-networks)

As Chrisoph mentioned in the chat (+1), you could consider [BPMN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Process_Model_and_Notation) as a diagrammatic way to symbolize your DES. Although it is possible to throw too much detail in for clients to quickly understand, such a diagrammatic approach to communicating discrete event simulation can be very effective.

However, if you want something more familiar to a mathematician I suggest you look into [Discrete Event System Specification (DEVS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEVS). There are actually some variants of this notation, but I am unfamiliar with their differences at this time. Pick whatever helps you clearly understand and communicate.

Even more generality can be obtained, if needed, by considering your DES as a [timed event system (TES)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timed_event_system). But this may be more general than needed for your purposes.